# Forge viewer - Custom Model Fragments position is changed after adding

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I'm adding a custom model with a number of meshes to the Forge viewer using this code

```
let cameras = camerasJSON.cameras[0];
let sceneBuilder = await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');
let modelBuilder = await sceneBuilder.addNewModel({
    modelNameOverride: 'Cameras',
    conserveMemory: false
})
cameras.forEach(camera => {
    const sphereGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 8, 8));
    const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(0, 1, 0) });
    let p = [+camera[2]/1000, +camera[3]/1000, +camera[4]/1000]
    const sphereTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(
        new THREE.Vector3(...p),
        new THREE.Quaternion(0,0,0,1),
        new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)
    );
        
    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    mesh.matrix = sphereTransform
    mesh.dbId = camera[0].split('_')[1];    
    modelBuilder.addMesh(mesh);
})
```

Then I try to retrieve position of a clicked fragment using this code

```
event.selections[0].model.getInstanceTree().enumNodeFragments(event.selections[0].dbIdArray[0], function (frag) {       
    let fragProxy = viewer.impl.getFragmentProxy(viewer.model, frag);
    let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();       
    fragProxy.getWorldMatrix(matrix);       
    let position = new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(matrix);
    console.log(position);
});
```

Retrieved position (and transform matrix itself) do not match to the initial position. Created meshes (green) are located correctly. But the actual fragment positions (red) do not match even relatively. Model is exploded for visibility.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNcES.png)

Removing global offset does not seem to have any effect.

Not sure if I'm retrieving position incorrectly, or the fragment's position is somehow transformed during adding. The main model does not have such issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking in the wrong model. To retrieve the position of the fragments added with modelBuilder, you should use modelBuilder.model and not viewer.model. And it becomes something like this:

```
const frags = modelBuilder.model.getFragmentList();
let matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
frags.getOriginalWorldMatrix(event.selections[0].fragIdsArray[0], 
matrix);
        
let position = new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(matrix);
```